# Back to top icon not showing on site, even though showing in local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a back to top button that is supposed to appear when scrolling past the top part of the page, and disappears when it goes to the top of the page.

It appears in my local site copy when testing, but on the internet, it isn't showing and only the text link shows instead.

The site is at: https://www.ivanteong.com

The back to top button is implemented with the following:

**Bottom of HTML page but above the JavaScript sources:**

```
<a href="#0" class="cd-top">Top</a></div>
```

**JavaScript sources at the bottom of the HTML page (When I put it in header there is problem with the menu scrolling):**

```
<!-- JS -->
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/counterup.min.js"></script>                 
<script src="../js/inview.min.js"></script>                 
<script src="../js/easypiechart.js"></script>                 
<script src="../js/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>                                     
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
<script src="../js/backtotop.js"></script>
```

**CSS styling for this in main.css:**

```
.cd-top {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  /* image replacement properties */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: GREY url(../images/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible, .cd-top.cd-fade-out, .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
  /* the button becomes visible */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.cd-top.cd-fade-out {
  /* if the user keeps scrolling down, the button is out of focus and becomes less visible */
  opacity: .5;
}
.no-touch .cd-top:hover {
background-color: #FF432E;
opacity: 1;
}
```

**backtotop.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
    var offset = 0,
        //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
        offset_opacity = 1500,
        //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
        scroll_top_duration = 1500,
        //grab the "back to top" link
        $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

    //hide or show the "back to top" link
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
            $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
    });

    //smooth scroll to top
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div,body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
            }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });
});
```

**cd-top-arrow.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="8,2.8 16,10.7 13.6,13.1 8.1,7.6 2.5,13.2 0,10.7 "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: i see the button with the arrow up, what problem do you have

Comment: there is no problem with your code i think , i can see the arrow

Comment: You see it? What browser you using? I don't see it on www.ivanteong.com on Chrome or Safari

Comment: i have checked with firefox and chrome http://prntscr.com/g5ruma

Comment: chrome v60 i can see the arrow

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

Comment: I see it on my local copy when I load up the HTML, but not on the internet copy

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/fj5uK link to what I'm seeing. There is "Top" link below but not the button with arrow. I just updated Chrome to v60 and deleted all history and reloaded the site, to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you are using a cached version of your code?

Comment: Nope, I deleted all my history for both browsers and reloaded the site and still the same. I don't understand why you are seeing different thing from me. In fact, I went to my mate's computer on Linux and he loaded it up, and he sees the same as me. Is Heroku loading up different versions of my code in different region?

Comment: Why is `offset_opacity = 1500` commented out?

Comment: Sorry minor mistake - edited. Still not working though.

Comment: Is !DOCTYPE the same locally and remotely?

Comment: I use: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> ...blah blah blah </html>

Comment: Are you sure you have uploaded your files to the server properly?  If I download main.css, the CSS rules you list do not seem to be in there.

Comment: Oh! This is weird: https://ivanteong.com/css/main.css has the updated version, but not https://www.ivanteong.com/css/main.css! But I'm redirecting everything to www

Comment: Sorry - I mean the www version dont have the updated version, but the non-www version has. Stackoverflow removed the hyperlink

Comment: You have a caching issue.

Comment: Everything works fine here.

Comment: Oh lol now I see the arrow! After I went to the main.css of the non-www version. BUT my mate's computer still don't see the button.

Comment: He goes to it from https://ivanteong.com

Comment: It's working in Safari now. I think it is a problem with Cloudflare. I use it to manage my DNS and manage my HTTPS forcing, as well as page redirect rules.

Comment: I also checked a new guy's computer and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching issue. I can't be 100% sure but I suspect that it has something to do with Cloudflare, which I use to manage my DNS, enforce HTTPS and redirect traffic from non-www to www. Paul LeBeau found that the css file is not updated, and I discovered that it is not updated for the www version, but the non-www is updated. After I loaded up these 2 variants of CSS, I don't know what happened but it works again. Maybe I "forced" Cloudflare to update the CSS file to the latest version and it couldn't use the cached copy of the CSS for the www site.

UPDATE: I'm sure this is Cloudflare's caching issue. I got the same problem again after changing the CSS for a loading animation for page loading. This problem is resolved if I want to make sure that Cloudflare only caches the latest copy of the files, by purging everything on Cloudflare's cache. Then it will have no problems loading up the latest code for my DNS.